# How to override / disable Zend Default path searching

Tags: zend-framework, autoload

i'm having some performance issues with some of the overhead that zend seems to be doing by default.
Given the namespace of my custom library in my application.ini file zend seems to search for same files in it's default library directories before it finally finds the right file it's look for.

Is there any way to disable this or make zend only look in the paths i specify?

Thanks.

Comment: have u tried looking into Zend's Auto loader class?

Answer (score 0):

This manual page on [Class loading performance](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html) may be of help to you.

They outline several ways to improve class loading, optimizing your include path, and using a cache to store the location of plugins so it doesn't need to search for them every time.

Hopefully following some of the methods mentioned there can solve some of your performance issues.